# Number of Abelian Groups of Order 36

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, gre-exam

GRE Subject Test Question:

Up to isomorphism, how many abelian groups are there of order 36?

The answer given is 4 and the explanation is as follows: Let *G* be an abelian group with order *n*. Then *G* is isomorphic to the products of the form $$Z_{(p_1^{n_1})} \times Z_{(p_2^{n_2})} \times \cdots \times Z_{(p_k^{n_k})}$$ where the $p_j$'s are not necessarily distinct, are the primes in the factorization of *n* and that $(p_1^{n_1})(p_2^{n_2}) \cdots (p_k^{n_k})=n$. Here $Z_n$ denotes the cyclic group of $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ under addition modulo *n*. For $n = 36 = 2^2 3^2$, G is isomorphic to $$Z_{(2^2)} \times Z_{(3^2)} \\ Z_{(2^1)} \times Z_{(2^1)} \times Z_{(3^2)} \\ Z_{(2^2)} \times Z_{(3^1)} \times Z_{(3^1)} \\ Z_{(2^1)} \times Z_{(2^1)} \times Z_{(3^1)} \times Z_{(3^1)}$$

I have two questions:

1. Could someone provide me with a link to a proof of the statement that *G* is isomorphic to the products of the form $Z_{(p_1^{n_1})} \times Z_{(p_2^{n_2})} \times \cdots \times Z_{(p_k^{n_k})}$ ?
2. Why does $Z_n$ denote the cyclic group of $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ under addition modulo *n*?

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a basic question. I'm a physics major trying to make the transition to applied mathematics in graduate school and I'm afraid my abstract mathematics are rather weak!

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Finite_Abelian_Groups

Comment: $Z_n $ denote {$0,1,2,3....,n-1$}, that is $Z_8$ what you have written

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth Thank you so much for the link, it's exactly what I was looking for. Regarding your second comment, that is what I thought. $Z_n$ refers to the cyclic group of integers under addition modulo *n*. So when the book explanation says that $Z_n$ denotes the cyclic group of $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ under addition modulo *n*, would you agree that it's a misprint? I was having trouble understanding why the set of integers would stop at 7 when *n* could in fact be much larger than 7.

Comment: yaeh or may be he was taking $n=7$

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification. Really appreciate your help!